# Compare two array and get all differences

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I have two arrays like this.

```
$array1=array(1,2,3,4,5,7);
$array2=array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

So, the output should bring the difference in both arrays.

The output should be.

1,2,3,4,5 -> These numbers exist in both arrays, **so these should be ignored**.

7 and 6 -> These numbers are the un-common in both arrays, so I need these values in array.

The output should be 7 & 6.

Help me out. I have tried `array_diff` and other array elements.

Comment: Um, array_diff returns an array. So why can't you use the array it returns?

Comment: hjaffer: if you ask questions here, you'll find that what @Puciek is saying will be said often. In general, readers here wanting you to try first isn't intended to be rude; it's just intended to teach people how to self-learn, and to ward off questions where absolutely no prior effort has been expended (a.k.a. "help vampires"). Thus, if you add in _your current code attempt_ into all questions, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this

```
array_merge(array_diff($array1,$array2),array_diff($array2,$array1))
```

Comment: I wonder if array_diff(array_merge($array1, $array2), array_intersect($array1, $array2)) would be any quicker.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
    if($value != $array2[$key]) {
        echo "\$array1[" . $key . "] (" . $value . ") is different to \$array2[" . $key . "] (" . $array2[$key] . "<br />";
    }
}
```