# Compare 2 arrays for difference with some values repeating

Tags: php, arrays, excel

I have 2 arrays to compare and I am using `array_diff` to compute the difference of columns as follows:

```
//array1 is as static array I have created to validate the sheet columns
$array1 = array('Category','Subcategory','Unknown','Age','0-9','Unknown','Region','Zone'); 

// array2 is coming dynamically from excel sheet columns so user can change the names
$array2 = array('Category','Subcategory','Unknowns','Age','0-9','Unknown','Region'); 

$diff = array_diff($array1,$array2);
$columnNames = implode(',',$diff);
if(!$diff){
   return true;
}
else{
  echo 'Some columns are missing:'. $columnNames ;
}
```

**output:** `Zone`

**Expected output:** `Zone, Unknowns`

The above code works fine if `Unknown` columns are unchanged. I know array_diff will only check the first array and compare the values present in next array. But, I want to compare these arrays and display user a message that some columns are missing and their names. So, here if one of the column is changed to `Unknowns` in excel sheet i.e `array2` then it should show the error message `Some columns are missing: Zone, Unknowns`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this using array_diff_assoc function in PHP:

```
     //array1 is as static array I have created to validate the sheet columns
 $array1 = array('Category','Subcategory','Unknown','Age','0-9','Unknown','Region','Zone'); 

 // array2 is coming dynamically from excel sheet columns so user can change the names
 $array2 = array('Category','Subcategory','Unknowns','Age','0-9','Unknown','Region'); 

 $diff = array_diff_assoc($array1,$array2);
 $columnNames = implode(',',$diff);

 echo $columnNames;
```

For your reference go to this site http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php

Comment: sorry my bad, just checked again and it works for me. Thanks! accepted because it is simpler and works fine for empty columns as well

Answer (score 3):

You can substrct the intersect of the two arrays from the union of the two arrays. **[Live Demo](https://eval.in/813152)**.

```
$array = array_diff(array_merge($array1, $array2), array_intersect($array1, $array2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
array_merge(array_diff($array1,$array2),array_diff($array2,$array1))
```

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16356205/4895810